OpportunityTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101
I'm not sure if you can help. I'm just an admin, not a developer. but when I try and Mass Update using Dataloader, I get that error message. Wondering if anyone could fix it for me so I don't get that error. Thanks!
This is the Apex Class code:
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler {
    public static void manageOpportunities(List<Opportunity> oppList, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOppMap){
        Map<Id, Set<Id>> leadIdOppIdSetMap = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
        List<Opportunity> convertedLeadOppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        set<string> parentLeadIds = new set<string>();        
                
        for(Opportunity objOpp : oppList){
            if(objOpp.Primary_Contact__c == null && objOpp.Primary_Lead__c == null){
                if(objOpp.FromLeadConversion__c && objOpp.Converted_Lead_Id__c != null){
                    parentLeadIds.add(objOpp.Converted_Lead_Id__c.left(15));
                    convertedLeadOppList.add(objOpp);
                }else{
                    objOpp.Primary_Contact__c.addError('Please select Primary Contact or Primary Lead');
                    objOpp.Primary_Lead__c.addError('Please select Primary Contact or Primary Lead');
                }
            }

            //For Insert and Update
            if((trigger.isInsert && objOpp.Primary_Lead__c != null) ||
               (trigger.isUpdate && oldOppMap != null && oldOppMap.containsKey(objOpp.Id) &&
                objOpp.Primary_Lead__c != null && oldOppMap.get(objOpp.Id).Primary_Lead__c != objOpp.Primary_Lead__c)){
                    if(!leadIdOppIdSetMap.containsKey(objOpp.Primary_Lead__c)){
                        leadIdOppIdSetMap.put(objOpp.Primary_Lead__c, new Set<Id>());
                    }
                    leadIdOppIdSetMap.get(objOpp.Primary_Lead__c).add(objOpp.Id);
                }   
            
            //Convert leads by Id
            Map<Id, Lead> convertedLeadMap = leadIdOppIdSetMap.size()>0? convertLead(leadIdOppIdSetMap.keySet()): null;
            if(convertedLeadMap != null && convertedLeadMap.size() > 0){
                for(Opportunity objOppt : oppList){
                    if(objOppt.Primary_Lead__c != null && convertedLeadMap.containsKey(objOppt.Primary_Lead__c)){
                        objOppt.AccountId = convertedLeadMap.get(objOppt.Primary_Lead__c).ConvertedAccountId;
                        objOppt.Primary_Contact__c = convertedLeadMap.get(objOppt.Primary_Lead__c).ConvertedContactId;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //Update Primary Contact for opportunity from Lead conversion
            Map<String, string> primaryContactMap = new Map<String, string>();
            for(Contact objCon : [SELECT Id, Converted_Lead_Id__c FROM Contact WHERE Converted_Lead_Id__c IN :parentLeadIds]){
                if(objCon.Converted_Lead_Id__c != null){
                    primaryContactMap.put(objCon.Converted_Lead_Id__c, objCon.Id);
                }
            }
            for(Opportunity objOppt : convertedLeadOppList){
                if(objOppt.Primary_Contact__c == null && objOppt.Primary_Lead__c == null){
                    if(objOppt.FromLeadConversion__c && objOppt.Converted_Lead_Id__c != null && primaryContactMap.containsKey(objOppt.Converted_Lead_Id__c.left(15))){
                        objOppt.Primary_Contact__c = primaryContactMap.get(objOppt.Converted_Lead_Id__c);
                        objOppt.Primary_Lead__c = objOppt.Converted_Lead_Id__c;
                    }else{
                        objOppt.Primary_Contact__c.addError('Please select Primary Contact or Primary Lead');
                        objOppt.Primary_Lead__c.addError('Please select Primary Contact or Primary Lead');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static Map<id,Lead> convertLead(Set<Id> leadIdSet){
        list<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new list<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(Lead myLead : [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Id IN: leadIdSet]){
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(myLead.Id);
            lc.convertedStatus = 'Qualified';
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
            leadConverts.add(lc);
        }
        if(!leadConverts.isEmpty()){
            Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcrList = Database.convertLead(leadConverts, false);
        }
        List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT Id, ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId FROM Lead WHERE isConverted = true AND ConvertedContactId != null AND Id IN: leadIdSet];
        return !leadList.isEmpty()? new Map<Id, Lead>(leadList): null;
    }
}


The issue is almost certainly with for(Contact objCon : [SELECT Id, Converted_Lead_Id__c FROM Contact WHERE Converted_Lead_Id__c IN :parentLeadIds]){, which is itself inside of another for loop. Queries inside of loops are problematic.

And, while it is likely possible for someone to fix this, this is really something that you should hire a contractor for. Personally, I'm willing to go to some lengths to help people learn, but I'm not going to do someone's work for them for free.

Thanks Derek! I appreciate it.

@DerekF - this actually helped immensely. i just put that into chatgpt and wala! :) Appreciate it.

If you need a workaround in the meantime, using a smaller batch size in dataloader would help. Since that query is running for every Opportunity, your batch size would need to be under 100 (but probably something closer to around 50).

Also, be very careful with chatGPT. It can often provide results that are between bad and terrible. Copy/pasting code that you do not understand is a recipe for (eventual) disaster.

@DerekF - NOTED!! ok - sounds good on the batching. I'll try that first before updating code that I don't know about - I am learning how to code but its slow and i'm just in the beginning stages

I massaged your code a bit to address the SOQL queries in loops. It should compile, but I didn't verify since I do not have your custom fields in my org. You can try this:
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler {
  public static void manageOpportunities(List<Opportunity> oppList, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOppMap) {
    Set<Id> leadIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    List<Opportunity> convertedLeadOppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    Set<String> parentLeadIds = new Set<String>();

    for (Opportunity objOpp : oppList) {
      if (objOpp.Primary_Contact__c == null && objOpp.Primary_Lead__c == null) {
        if (objOpp.FromLeadConversion__c && objOpp.Converted_Lead_Id__c != null) {
          parentLeadIds.add(objOpp.Converted_Lead_Id__c.left(15));
          convertedLeadOppList.add(objOpp);
        } else {
          objOpp.Primary_Contact__c.addError('Please select Primary Contact or Primary Lead');
          objOpp.Primary_Lead__c.addError('Please select Primary Contact or Primary Lead');
        }
      }

      //For Insert and Update
      if (
        (Trigger.isInsert && objOpp.Primary_Lead__c != null) ||
        (Trigger.isUpdate &&
        oldOppMap != null &&
        oldOppMap.containsKey(objOpp.Id) &&
        objOpp.Primary_Lead__c != null &&
        oldOppMap.get(objOpp.Id).Primary_Lead__c != objOpp.Primary_Lead__c)
      ) {
        leadIdSet.add(objOpp.Primary_Lead__c);
      }
    }

    //Convert leads by Id
    Map<Id, Lead> convertedLeadMap = convertLead(leadIdSet);
    if (!convertedLeadMap.isEmpty()) {
      for (Opportunity objOpp : oppList) {
        if (objOpp.Primary_Lead__c != null && convertedLeadMap.containsKey(objOpp.Primary_Lead__c)) {
          objOpp.AccountId = convertedLeadMap.get(objOpp.Primary_Lead__c).ConvertedAccountId;
          objOpp.Primary_Contact__c = convertedLeadMap.get(objOpp.Primary_Lead__c).ConvertedContactId;
        }
      }
    }

    //Update Primary Contact for opportunity from Lead conversion
    Map<String, String> primaryContactMap = new Map<String, String>();
    for (Contact objCon : [
      SELECT Id, Converted_Lead_Id__c
      FROM Contact
      WHERE Converted_Lead_Id__c IN :parentLeadIds
    ]) {
      if (objCon.Converted_Lead_Id__c != null) {
        primaryContactMap.put(objCon.Converted_Lead_Id__c, objCon.Id);
      }
    }

    for (Opportunity objOpp : convertedLeadOppList) {
      if (objOpp.Primary_Contact__c == null && objOpp.Primary_Lead__c == null) {
        if (
          objOpp.FromLeadConversion__c &&
          objOpp.Converted_Lead_Id__c != null &&
          primaryContactMap.containsKey(objOpp.Converted_Lead_Id__c.left(15))
        ) {
          objOpp.Primary_Contact__c = primaryContactMap.get(objOpp.Converted_Lead_Id__c);
          objOpp.Primary_Lead__c = objOpp.Converted_Lead_Id__c;
        } else {
          objOpp.Primary_Contact__c.addError('Please select Primary Contact or Primary Lead');
          objOpp.Primary_Lead__c.addError('Please select Primary Contact or Primary Lead');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static Map<Id, Lead> convertLead(Set<Id> leadIdSet) {
    list<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    for (Id leadId : leadIdSet) {
      Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
      lc.setLeadId(leadId);
      lc.convertedStatus = 'Qualified';
      lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
      leadConverts.add(lc);
    }
        
    if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
      Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcrList = Database.convertLead(leadConverts, false);
    }
    Map<Id, Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id, Lead>(
      [
        SELECT Id, ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId
        FROM Lead
        WHERE isConverted = TRUE AND ConvertedContactId != NULL AND Id IN :leadIdSet
      ]
    );
    return leadMap;
  }
}

